# php mysql ORDER BY query error

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following attributes of posts table -
id,title,cat_id,contents,date_posted.
For the categories table:
id and name.

I'm getting the error in $query.="ORDER BY posts.id";

```
$posts=array();
$query=("SELECT posts.id AS post_id, categories.id AS category_id, title, contents, date_posted, categories.name AS name FROM posts INNER JOIN categories ON categories.id = posts.cat_id");

if(isset($id))
{
$id=(int)$id;
$query.="WHERE posts.id={$id}";
}

$query.="ORDER BY posts.id DESC";
$query=mysql_query($query);
```

Comment: Assuming you are using php, try using mysqli. Mysql on its own has ben depretiated. That may be causing the error

Comment: you do realize what _concatenation_ does? _whitespaces_ probably? And what happens if  `if(!isset($id))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query construction seems incorrect to me. There should be a whitespace before a `WHERE` clause and the same goes for `ORDER BY`.

```
$posts = array();
$query = ("SELECT posts.id AS post_id, categories.id AS category_id, title, contents, date_posted, categories.name AS name FROM posts INNER JOIN categories ON categories.id = posts.cat_id");

if (isset($id)) {
  $id=(int)$id;
  $query .= " WHERE posts.id={$id}"; // note whitespace before WHERE
}

$query .= " ORDER BY posts.id DESC"; // note whitespace before ORDER BY here
$query = mysql_query($query);
```